# JavaFX Controlsfx library Check-ComboBox autocomplete

Tags: java, javafx

I have check-combo box I have taken it from controlsFX library which has more than 80 items in it. How can I write check-Combobox autocomplete logic? As while selecting items from CheckComboBox I need to scroll down and search item manually. I want a search option for it.

Comment: use a listener for a key pressed in the combo... and filter + update

Comment: But I am not able to type text in check-combobox.

Answer (score 0):

The check-combobox control is not editable and as such you cannot make it auto complete. Use combobox and set the cellFactory, extend ListCell and add checkbox